# PHP: Converting a string to an multidimensional array

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a string to an array when, however, I want to create multidimensional arrays when the string has items in brackets.

For example, if the string as passed: (Mary Poppins) Umbrella (Color Yellow)

I would want to create an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => mary [1] => poppins) [1] => umbrella [2] => Array ( [0] => color [1] => yellow) )
```

I was able to get the data placed into an array through this:

```
preg_match_all('/\(([A-Za-z0-9 ]+?)\)/', stripslashes($_GET['q']), $subqueries);
```

But I am having trouble getting the items placed in the multidimensional arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: She's called *"Mary Poppins"* BTW.

Comment: Use recursion (recursive regexp and recursive funcall)

Comment: Would there be nested brackets ? `hello(cool (foo bar) (troll (attempt baz)))` ?

Comment: There would be no nested brackets.

Comment: On the off-chance that you are allowed to control the format of the string, JSON notation would be much easier.

Comment: You guys, Mary Poppins used a **black** umbrella. Mary Poppens (with an e), on the other hand, used a **yellow** umbrella. Please make sure you are familiar with the matter before editing questions that are practically perfect in every way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some PHP-Fu:

```
$string = '(Mary Poppens) Umbrella (Color Yellow)';
$array = array();
preg_replace_callback('#\((.*?)\)|[^()]+#', function($m)use(&$array){
    if(isset($m[1])){
        $array[] = explode(' ', $m[1]);
    }else{
        $array[] = trim($m[0]);
    }
}, $string);
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mary
            [1] => Poppens
        )

    [1] => Umbrella 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Color
            [1] => Yellow
        )

)
```

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/mH3oK#v530)

> <sub>**Note that you need PHP 5.3+ since I'm using an anonymous function.**</sub>

---

Got compatible ?

```
$string = '(Mary Poppens) Umbrella (Color Yellow)';

preg_match_all('#\((.*?)\)|[^()]+#', $string, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($match as $m){
    if(isset($m[1])){
        $array[] = explode(' ', $m[1]);
    }else{
        $array[] = trim($m[0]);
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/ORb4g#v430)

> <sub>**Tested on PHP 4.3+**</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have prefaced. I am on PHP 5.2.x

Comment: Still useable, just replace the anonymous function with a regular function and pass the name as a callback

Comment: and you really should upgrade to newer versions of PHP !